# Deploying an api with google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I made an api for my angular app, and now I want to deploy it. However, I can't require my server.js (which is the entry point for the app with all routes declared et cetera), file from inside the functions folder. How do I go about this?

I have tried to move all my prior code to the functions folder, which did not work (even after removing and reinstalling node modules and changing entry points for the firebase.json).
I moved the backend away from the angular project into its own separate folder. This did not work either.

In my functions index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('../server.js');

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And server.js is outside of the functions folder.

Expected to be able to deploy my function, instead got

```
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../server.js'.
```

EDIT:

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|-- database
|   |-- database.js
|   |-- db_config.js
|   `-- models
|       `-- User.js
|-- firebase.json
|-- firestore.indexes.json
|-- firestore.rules
|-- functions
|   |-- node_modules  
|   |-- index.js
|   |-- package-lock.json
|   `-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
|-- node_modules
|-- routes
|   `-- api.js
|-- server.js
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that file server.js is not located in the folder just above index.js ...

Comment: @cocool97 I've updated the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can include local Node.js modules for the dependencies of your Cloud Functions. You can achieve this by declaring your modules in package.json using the file: prefix, as explained in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#including_local_nodejs_modules_as_part_of_your_deployment_package).

The code for this local module should not be in your node_modules folder. You can simply store it at the root of your function’s directory.

Comment: It seems that I cannot use the server.js inside of my functions, I do not know why. Tried the "file: .." to include my local project. Does not work, thanks for good info though. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you upload the source code from local ZIP files, ‘Index.js’ should be in the root directory of the zipped file.  Based on your folder structure, ‘server.js’ is in the root directory, which should be at the same level as ‘index.js’. So in order to require ‘server.js’ when ‘index.js’ is located at the root, the code is: `const app = require('./server.js')`;
A single dot Indicates to import ‘server.js’ from the same folder. Since ‘index.js’ should be in the root directory of the uploaded file, its parent folder is meaningless.